# Ruby syntax checking in vim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim

I use vim with various plugins for editing ruby code.  I have proper syntax highlighting set up but I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to get ruby syntax *checking*, similar to what you might see in an IDE such as visual studio, radrails, etc?

Something that would simply turn stuff red or break highlighting when I'm missing an 'end' or have an improperly constructed line of code would be sweet.

I googled and came across this plugin, http://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/tree/master but I was wondering if anyone had any better suggestions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

awesome_person is right, `":w !ruby -c"` will do. To make it more convenient, add this line in your ~/.vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType ruby map <F9> :w<CR>:!ruby -c %<CR>
```

Then the syntax gets checked on pressing F9 key.

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted but this works pretty well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

You can syntax check the current buffer in ruby without downloading any plugins. The command is:

```
:w !ruby -c
```

Answer (score 10):

I think the existing answers are outdated.  A ruby compiler plugin comes with vim now, so all you *should* need to do now is run `:compiler ruby`, or add this command to your `~/.vim/ftplugin/ruby.vim` file (creating it if necessary).  Then, not only will running `:make` syntax check your code, it will put you in vim [quickfix mode](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/issues/161), enabling you to jump directly to errors.

I say "should" because the compiler plugin misses the point a bit and doesn't set `makeprg` sensibly.  Here is what I actually put in `~/.vim/ftplugin/ruby.vim`:

```
compiler ruby
setlocal makeprg=ruby\ -wc\ %
```

I [suggested](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/issues/161) that this be the default.

Comment: Yeah I think this is the best way. Then you can use :cn to go to the next error message in the list after running :make as well.

Answer (score 0):

The rails.vim plugin does excellent syntax highlighting, as long as you stay within some of its formatting confines. Couple this with auto-indentation (ggVG=) and you should be able to get a general sense of if the document is well formed, or not.

Comment: Just for future reference, gg=G does the same and will save you a couple keystrokes.

Comment: Word.  I was aware of that stuff, but I was hoping that someone might know of something a little more ide-like.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a few people have tried this, but no one has tried too hard.  Personally I recommend using autotest in a separate terminal window.

[Try this](http://got-ravings.blogspot.com/2009/06/vim-pr0n-syntax-checking-on-go.html), if you just want syntex errors.

If you want errors that happen at runtime as well, you might [like this instead.](http://beans.seartipy.com/2006/09/22/develop-ruby-applications-using-vim-70-editor/)

Comment: Your answer has nothing helpful. It contains only links. If you put links, please try to include more context, or at least an idea of what I might find when clicking on them.

Answer (score 0):

Check out using the CTK plugin:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2618

and try this in your .vimrc:

```
" Compile Ruby code after writing (show warnings/errors)
function! Compile()
  " don't compile if it's an Rspec file (extra warnings)
  let name = expand('<afile>')
  if name !~ 'spec'
    CC
  endif
endfunction
autocmd BufWritePost *.rb call Compile()
```

That (with ctk.vim) will perform a compile every time when the file is saved.

Comment: I should clarify, by "compile", I meant that it will run your ruby file with Ruby's syntax checking option (-w).